# getResourceAsStream returns null but File.canRead() returns true

Tags: java, file-io

I have the current file structure

-Boggle

```
*src
    -java files
*data
    -dictionary.txt
*derived
     -Boggle.jar
```

Typing

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()
```

gives

/Boggle/derived/

I am trying to load the dictionary.txt file with

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("../data/dictionary.txt")
```

but this returns null

However when I try

```
new File("../data/dictionary.txt").canRead()
```

this returns true.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is `data` part of your classpath? Do you use an IDE? Have declared it as source folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data/dictionary` is not considered an embedded resource, but is simply an external resource, in this case, a simple File

If you want to to use `getResource`, then `data/dictionary` needs to be included within the context of the class path.

You can do this by including `data/dictionary` within one of the applications Jar files or setting the class path to include the parent directory containing the `data` directory

Comment: I have a build.xml file. I am trying to include data directory by adding                                                                 <path id="class.path">
    <fileset dir="lib">
      <include name="**/*.jar"/>
      <include name="**/*.zip"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="data">                 //added this
      <include name="dictionary.txt"/>   //added this
    </fileset>
  </path>                                                                                                                        but i'm getting unexpected file on path warning and the resource is still not found

Comment: Sorry for the question in a question! are there other ways to add this file to the class path?

Comment: You want to included the parent directory of `data` in the classpath, so that when searching for the file (using `getResource`) you would still be looking for `%classpath%/data/dictionary.txt` OR have the build script include the `data` directory and it's contents as part of the Jar'ing process